# regex grep/egrep problems

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Based on searches on stackoverflow, I found out the difference between grep/egrep, but I still can't determine why this doesn't work.  I've even check it at https://regex101.com/ and it shows it checked out right.

Regex:

```
.*ping[\/] or ping\D
```

searching against (text.txt):

```
path=/bin/ping6
path=/bin/ping
```

I'm trying to skip the first and only find the 2nd.

If I would do grep ping text.txt it finds both which isn't what I want.

```
grep -e ".*ping[\/]" text.txt [doesn't work]
egrep ".*ping[\/]" text.txt [doesn't work]
grep -P ".*ping[\/]" text.txt [doesn't work]
```

I did get this to work but not sure why:

```
grep -P "ping\D" text.txt [worked]
grep -e "ping\D" text.txt [doesn't work]
```

What am I failing to understand with grep -e/egrep/grep -p/regex?

When I man grep -P it said it's highly experimental and not to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\D` is the letter "D" for extended regular expressions. For perl regexes, `\D` is a **non**-digit and `\d` is a digit.

To search for "ping" followed optionally by a digit followed by a slash, you want:

```
grep 'ping[[:digit:]]\?/'
grep -E 'ping[[:digit:]]?/'
```

To search for "ping" **not** followed by a digit:

```
grep -E 'ping($|[^[:digit:]])'   # ping then end-of-line or non-digit
grep -P 'ping(?!\d)'
```

GNU extended regular expressions  [documented here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/posix_002degrep-regular-expression-syntax.html#posix_002degrep-regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: Well that explains why it works for grep -P and not grep -e.  I actually don't want the 6 so i only want the word ping but ping 6 is first and it matches.

Comment: Isn't `grep -E 'ping($|[^[:digit:]])'` the same as `grep -E 'ping[^[:digit:]]'`? Since the `$` anchor is a non digit?

Comment: if the string is `/bin/ping`, then the pattern `'ping[^[:digit:]]'` **will not match** because there is no character following "ping" and `[^[:digit:]]` must match one character. The `$` anchor matches the empty string after "ping".

Comment: i saw there are several that are [[::]] and have something inside of them.  Why does it have double [[]] instead of just []?

Comment: Because `[:digit:]` is special syntax *inside* the `[...]` brackets. See the [regex(7)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/regex.7.html) man page.

Comment: @glenn you made me realize i had a typo in the question.  I wrote the trailing slash where it doesn't actually have one. so its just /bin/ping

Comment: Did you try that? What happened? What does the documentation say about that regex?

Comment: ping [^[:digit:]] worked for ping.  But why doesn't that match /usr/bin/at  if that is changed to "$f"[^[:digit:]]? I know I only asked for ping and I don't know if I need to start a new question, but I added it back in to my bigger script and it works for 99% of what is read it except for one.  So if its path=/usr/bin/at or path=/bin/ping both next characters are a space it should work.

Comment: is `"$f"[^[:digit:]]` inside single quotes?

Comment: `grep '/usr/bin/at[^[:digit:]]' test.txt` works fine but my script doesn't.

`VALUE1=$(my find command it returns several /usr/bin or /usr/sbin paths)

find command again -print | while read f; do

 #this just is checking to see if it is already in the file
 VALUE2=$(grep -e '"$f"[^[:digit:]]' test.txt

 if [ -z "$VALUE2" ]; then
  do something
 else
  do something
 fi

done`

if i take the ' ' away it works for everyone except /usr/bin/at why?

Comment: variables are not expanded within single quotes. Please search for similar problems, there are plenty of answers

Comment: @glennjackman grep -e ''"$f"'[^[:digit:]]' worked.  I found someone suggested using set -x to see exactly what was happening.  It works exactly as it should now.